# lightning treegrid

Tags: lightning-web-components, edit, lightningtreegrid

I have a lightning tree grid.. I want to edit on of the columns ...
is inline edit possible in data grid tree .
[image]

I have tried to make the column editable but it does not support
[image]

Is there anyways we can achieve this behavior

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`lightning-tree-grid`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation) unambiguously states

> Inline editing and sorting of columns are not supported

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Write your own component that supports it.

Comment: is there any example ..I am bit new to LWC and salesforce .. thank you .. help is very much appreciated

Comment: If you're new to LWC I would recommend starting with Trailhead. This is not really an introductory use case.